# What does "Connecting to internet via proxy server" mean?

Tags: proxy

At my school, sometime the websites are accessible only when connected to a proxy server provided by school. So, unless the proxy server settings are configured in firefox/chrome, we can't connect to the internet/access the websites.

I am trying to understand how a proxy server like this works in terms of high level network topology. However, I am not able to find much success on the internet.

My main concerns is, If I am connected to the internet/wifi, I should be able to access website in the browser. Why does the traffic have to routed through proxy server, for me to access websites.

Comment: The proxy server is there to monitor and filter web traffic.

Comment: just google "proxy server"; skimming trough the top results would have been quicker than typing this question. https://www.google.com/search?q=proxy+server&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=

Comment: “If I am connected to the internet”—you are not. The proxy server is.

Comment: @DanielB What I meant was wifi. If I am connected to the wifi, I should be able to access websites without having to go through proxy server.

Comment: No, why? There is no requirement for a network to be directly connected to the internet.

Comment: @DanielB If I am connected to wifi through router, and the router is connected to the internet by definition, should't I be connected to the internet. Why is proxy server playing a role in that? What am I missing in this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any system on a network to talk to a computer outside of that network, it has to send traffic to a router on that network.

It's possible to configure a router to block all outgoing traffic wanting to reach somewhere on the Internet except certain machines on the network, such as a proxy server.

So in your case, the proxy server is another system on the network, and is probably the only device on the network the router will allow to talk through to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

The standard definition for "Proxy server" uses an Internet server
to pass communications to the Internet, usually used to disguise one's
geographical coordinates, so it looks like this:

> PC --- router --- Internet --- proxy server --- Internet --- target

In your school configuration, it's possible that they have only
one server with access to the Internet with a firewall,
for security reasons.
This isn't, strictly speaking, a proxy server but rather a tunnel.

In this case, this may look like:

> PC -- uni network -- uni proxy server -- uni network -- uni router -- Internet -- target

Where uni proxy server and uni router can also be implemented as one computer.

With the latest case, you will not be able to connect to the Internet,
except via the proxy.
WiFi or Ethernet change nothing, since in the end all routes lead to
the uni router via only the uni proxy server.

Comment: That does not make any sense to me. I was under the impression that school's proxy would be somewhere on school's network like me. By your topology diagram, I should be able to connect to the internet without proxy.

Comment: Ah, this is a somewhat bastardy usage of terms which I added above.